# How many ways exist to Store data from laravel form to database?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, as far as I know, there three ways to store data form into DB, please correct me if I am wrong:

First way: instantiating an object from the model

```php
$tutor = new Tutor();
$tutor ->name = $request->name;
// in some tutorials they use: 
// $tutor->name = request('name');
// what is the difference?
$tutor ->salary = $request->salary;
$tutor->save();
```

Second way: converting the object into an array

```php
$tutor = array([
  'name'   => $request->name, // vs 'name' => $request->input('name'), what is the difference?
  'salary' => $request->salary
]);
$tutor->save(); // Do I need to save here?
```

Third way: using a global helper method

```php
$tutor = Tutor::create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> difference between `request('name')` and `$request('name');`

`request()` is a global helper function that can be used anywhere to access the HTTP request object

`$request` is the parameter passed to the controller function which means **THE** request passed to this controller, would be useful when validating data via form request classes

> Do I need to save data here?

Second way shouldn't work at all as written, you may mean

```php
$tutor = new Tutor([
  'name'   => $request->name,
  'salary' => $request->salary
]);
$tutor->save();
```

which is manually stripping out additional form posted data, it's no different from

```php
$tutor = new Tutor();
$tutor->create(request()->only(['name', 'salary']));
```

> `$request->name` vs 'name' => $request->input('name')
>   what is the difference?

using the `input` method means grab the name parameter from a user input no matter what HTTP method was used `GET` or `POST` or to quote [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input)

**Retrieving An Input Value**

Using a few simple methods, you may access all of the user input from your `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance without worrying about which HTTP verb was used for the request. Regardless of the HTTP verb, the `input` method may be used to retrieve user input:

```
$name = $request->input('name');
```

Third way uses mass assignment from everything posted in the request including what you didn't intend from malicious users (hackers)

Avoid it at all costs

Hope this helps

Comment: Second method should be ```$tutor = new Tutor([
  'name'   => $request->name,
  'salary' => $request->salary
]);
$tutor->save();``` That should be what he meant to write.

Comment: @Saly3301
thank you soo much that really clarifies the concept for me. However, I have some inquiries to ensure my understanding.

- which way is more secured the first or the second and why?
- So if I wish to use the Global helper method `request` I can just use it directly. While if I wish to use the parameter `$request` passed to the controller then I have to invoke `use Illuminate\Http\Request` instance, correct?
- What differs when we use different HTTP methods??. In other words, what limitations does `input()` remove?